# Python transposing a column based on another column

Tags: python, transpose

I am trying to use Pandas to transpose the "Value" column in the first picture into the second picture where each ID has one line and all the values listed horizontally.

I'm a little rusty in my Python but feel like this shouldn't be too hard and am having trouble thinking where to start.

Any help appreciated.

[image: Staring data]
[image]

Comment: What do you have, lists, arrays, Pandas data frames, something else? Can you please give some piece of code from where we can start? And maybe give some idea of what have you thought to solve it so far?

Comment: Having a variable number of columns isn't really Pandas' forte, mostly because that kind of data is a nightmare to work with. I don't know what your goal is but you should consider whether it's really necessary to use the format you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @jdehesa thank you for pointing out the detail that was missing in my post. Apologies as I'm new to this community I still learning the level of detail to put. The answer by dataLeo below is exactly what I was looking for. I was in a Pandas DataFrame. As I currently only work in data wrangling in Pandas df, I assumed all tabular data would be done there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're working with a `pandas dataframe`, here's a quick workaround:

```
# Creating a dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 8, 5, 97, 4], ['A','A', 'B','C','C','C']]).T
df.columns = ['Value', 'ID']
df

    Value   ID
0   2       A
1   2       A
2   8       B
3   5       C
4   97      C
5   4       C

# Expected dataframe
dfn = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.ID)['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.values).values.tolist(), index=df.ID.unique())
dfn

    0   1       2
A   2   2.0     NaN
B   8   NaN     NaN
C   5   97.0    4.0

dfn.columns = ['Value'+str(i) for i in range(1, len(dfn.columns)+1)]
dfn.index.name = 'ID'
dfn

ID  Value1  Value2  Value3
A   2        2.0    NaN
B   8        NaN    NaN
C   5        97.0   4.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Sorry for not specifying better that I had a Pandas DataFrame. Right now that's all I work in so just assume that's where any tabular data is for everyone.

Comment: Good. You can also upvote answers which you find helpful ;)

Comment: I totally would but right now I don't have enough recorded reputations to up-vote the answer.